# Testing updated jar in project

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, jakarta-ee

I have a main java EE project in which I use multiple jar libraries.

For one of the specific jars, I am going into the original project of that jar, and updating its libraries, and re-importing the updated jar into the main project.

I am thinking of good ways to test that the updated jar still works in the application, so I decided upon looking for where the jar is being used. Is there a way in Eclipse to find every instance that the jar is being used (classes instantiated, methods called, etc)?

Should I just be looking for import statements or anything else?

Comment: Search for imports with the package name(s) that are used in the jar?

Comment: What is the next step after finding the classes which use the updated jar?  How are those classes actually tested?  Just making sure it complies?  Running unit tests?  Automated integration tests?  Manual integration tests?